# Display a count of Booleans from database

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm using flask. Database is sqlite3.
In short. I can make lists and I can tick them off as "finished", I want to show the numbers of finished lists in the users profile.

At this time it shows the same as "all lists"..

This is my List model:

```
class List(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    user = ForeignKeyField(
        rel_model=User,
        related_name='list'
    )
    content = TextField()
    finished = BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
       database = DATABASE
       order_by = ('-timestamp',)
```

This is my find finished lists function on the User model:

```
 def finished_lists(self):
    return List.select().where(
        (List.user == self) |
        (List.finished == True)
    )
```

This is the profile template:

```
{% extends "stream.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="">
        <h1>{{ user.username }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <div class="">
            <h5>Followers</h5>
            <p>{{ user.followers().count() }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <h5>Following</h5>
            <p>{{ user.following().count() }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <h5>Lists</h5>
            <p>{{ user.list.count() }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <h5>Finished</h5>
            <p>{{ user.finished_lists().count() }}</p>
       </div>

    </div>

    <div class="grid-25">
        {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
            {% if user != current_user %}
                {% if not user in current_user.following() %}
                    <a href="{{ url_for('follow', username=user.username) }}" class="small">Follow</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a href="{{ url_for('unfollow', username=user.username)     }}" class="small">Unfollow</a>

                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>

{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your finished list function you select all lists corresponding to the user **OR** (|) finished . Both conditions should be true to select finished lists so you need **and** (&)